# Integral of the sum of measurable functions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose ($f_n$) is a series of $\mu$-measurable function.If we have either $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\mu(f_n^+)<\infty$ or $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\mu(f_n^-)<\infty$, then how can we prove that 
$$
\mu(\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(f_n) 
$$
I want to use Fatou lemma here, but it seems I can't get the exact consequence.

Comment: Is $\mu$ a measure? If so, what do you mean with applying it to a function instead of a set?

Comment: $\mu$ is a measure, here $\mu(f)$ is equal to $\int fd\mu$.

Comment: Use Lebesgue's Monotone Convergence Theorem, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem#Lebesgue.27s_monotone_convergence_theorem

Comment: Thank you for your information. But the thing is that here the functions $f_n$ may not be nonnegative, so we need to fix the proof on the nonnegative cases.

Comment: I know. Use it on the positive and negative parts separately.

Comment: But then maybe we need to change the order of the sum? i.e. I wonder if $\mu(\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n)=\mu(\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n^+)-\mu(\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n^-)$ is right?

Comment: $\mu(\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n) = \mu(\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n^+ - \sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n^-) = \mu(\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n^+) -\mu(\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n^-)$ where the second equality follows from the definition of an integral of a signed function.